# return a specific type when Object is the return type in a method in Java

Tags: java, object, methods, return

I have a method `getValue` like this

```
public Object getValue() {
     return Integer.valueOf(0);
```

}

and a call in the main method:

```
getValue() + 5;
```

This is simplified.

How to get this working without casting in the main method, but instead how to cast the return type if possible?

Comment: Why not public int getValue() { return Integer.valueOf(0); }

Comment: You don't.  I think this is how it is.

Comment: How about a not-as-simplified version so we have some context as to the real problem?

Comment: @Robert I think the point is that he wants to return Object.

Comment: I cant return int because this is a sample, in my code there might be returned Double, Integer or String

Comment: Why not make the class generic instead of relying on type unsafe polymorphism?

Comment: If he wants to return an object so that the function can return a Double or an Integer or a String, then he is going to have to Cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use generics:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Number>{


  public T getValue(){
    //do something here
  }
}

MyClass<Integer> foo = new MyClass<Integer>();
foo.getValue()+5;
```

Comment: What do you think of MyClass<T extends Number> to avoid some problem with getValue() +5 ?

Comment: @EricR. Good call.  I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your method returns an Object, you're going to have to cast at some point or another to use the class specific functions of Integer, Double, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should not do that, if you wrote this function public Object getValue()
then why not change it to public Integer getValue() and return Integer.

If you also expect other types then over load the method public String getValue(), public Double getValue() etc. Use factory pattern to decide which method to call.

If you dont want to cast then you can't use Object as return type and still use getValue() + 5;

I also like elivine's response